# Need help refactoring tyepscript functions

Tags: typescript, refactoring

This is my first question on stackoverflow. Apologies if its not up to par. Ill try my best.

I have recently started an Angular project.

This question is how to **refactor 4 simple functions (which do the same thing) in typescript to make it into 1 function**. The function is a simple toggle, which open and reveals further content, and then hides it when closed.

At the moment I have **four divs with each having its own individual function**. All four do exactly the same thing.

You will notice in the HTML and tyepScript code that each toogleLinks function increases by 1. For example, **toogleLinks1()**, **toogleLinks2()**, **toogleLinks3()** etc.

Also variables used in the ngIf directive and ngClass directive for each Div also increase by 1.
For example, **ngIf** = "**toggle1**", **ngIf** = "**toggle2**", **ngIf** = "**toggle3**".

I will show the HTML and typescript code below.

I hope you all have the information you need.

**Thanks!!**

```
<div id = 'menu-main-links'>
  <div class = 'main-menu-link-item'>
    <!-- click event occurs here-->
    <div class = 'submenu-heading'  (click)="toogleLinks1($event)"  [ngClass]="status1 ? 'open' : 'close'">
      <h1>Platform</h1>
    </div> 

      <div class = 'sidebar-submenu' *ngIf = "toggle1" [ngClass]="status1 ? 'open' : 'close'">

      <!--revealed content goe here -->

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class = 'main-menu-link-item'>
    <!-- click event occurs here-->
    <div class = 'submenu-heading'  (click)="toogleLinks2($event)"  [ngClass]="status2 ? 'open' : 'close'">
      <h1>Platform</h1>
    </div> 

      <div class = 'sidebar-submenu' *ngIf = "toggle2" [ngClass]="status2 ? 'open' : 'close'">

      <!--revealed content goe here -->

    </div>
  </div>  

  <div class = 'main-menu-link-item'>
    <!-- click event occurs here-->
    <div class = 'submenu-heading'  (click)="toogleLinks3($event)"  [ngClass]="status3 ? 'open' : 'close'">
      <h1>Platform</h1>
    </div> 

      <div class = 'sidebar-submenu' *ngIf = "toggle3" [ngClass]="status3 ? 'open' : 'close'">

      <!--revealed content goe here -->

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class = 'main-menu-link-item'>
    <!-- click event occurs here-->
    <div class = 'about-us-heading'  (click)="toogleLinks4($event)"  [ngClass]="status4 ? 'open' : 'close'">
      <h1>Platform</h1>
    </div> 

      <div class = 'sidebar-submenu' *ngIf = "toggle4" [ngClass]="status4 ? 'open' : 'close'">

      <!--revealed content goe here -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>







export class LayoutComponent {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  toggle1 = false;
  status1 = false;

  toggle2 = false;
  status2 = false;

  toggle3 = false;
  status3 = false;

  toggle4 = false;
  status4 = false;
    



  toogleLinks1(event: Event){
    setTimeout( () =>{
      if (!this.toggle1) {
        this.toggle1 = true;
        this.status1 = !this.status1;
      } else{
        this.toggle1 = false;
        this.status1 = false;
      }
    },100)
  }

  toogleLinks2(event: Event){
    setTimeout( () =>{
      if (!this.toggle2) {
        this.toggle2 = true;
        this.status2 = !this.status1;
      } else{
        this.toggle2 = false;
        this.status2 = false;
      }
    },100)
  }

  toogleLinks3(event: Event){
    setTimeout( () =>{
      if (!this.toggle3) {
        this.toggle3 = true;
        this.status3 = !this.status2;
      } else{
        this.toggle3 = false;
        this.status3 = false;
      }
    },100)
  }

  toogleLinks4(event: Event){
    setTimeout( () =>{
      if (!this.toggle4) {
        this.toggle4 = true;
        this.status4 = !this.status3;
      } else{
        this.toggle4 = false;
        this.status4 = false;
      }
    },100)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactored current code in different ways.

**Solution 1:**
Create 1 child component in which you can pass the content and header as parameter. Toggling logic will remain in that child component. You can enhance this as per your requirement.

```
export class LinkComponent {
  @Input() title: string;
  status: boolean;

  toogleLinks(toggle: string) {
    this.status = !this.status;
  }
}

<div class="main-menu-link-item">
  <div
    class="submenu-heading" (click)="toogleLinks('toggle1')"
    [ngClass]="status ? 'open' : 'close'">
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div
    class="sidebar-submenu" *ngIf="status"
    [ngClass]="status ? 'open' : 'close'">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

And use that component in parent one.

```
<div id="menu-main-links">
  <app-link title="Platform 1">
    <h2>Platform 1</h2>
  </app-link>
  <app-link title="Platform 2">
      <h2>Platform 2</h2>
  </app-link>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:**
You can create 1 function in which you just pass the variable name which will handle the toggling for that part.

```
  toggle1 = false;
  toggle2 = false;
  toggle3 = false;
  toggle4 = false;

  toogleLinks(toggle: string) {
    this[toggle] = !this[toggle];
  }
```

And in your template pass the variable name in that function.

```
<div class="main-menu-link-item">
    <div class="submenu-heading" (click)="toogleLinks('toggle1')" 
    [ngClass]="toggle1 ? 'open' : 'close'">
        <h3>Platform 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-submenu" *ngIf="toggle1" 
    [ngClass]="status1 ? 'open' : 'close'">
        <h2>Platform 1</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you dont need the status variable for maintaining CSS classes you can use the `toggle` variable for that.

Working codesandbox:-

https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-comon-function-qjsou?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Hey Vimal, thanks for the amazing answer!

I attempted at solution number 2.

I keep getting the following error message in the console:

** " No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'LayoutComponent'. " **

This is concerning the toggelLinks functions in your example, 

  toggleLinks(toggle: string) {
    this[toggle] = !this[toggle];
  }


Thanks again!

Comment: Please share your code, as you can see it is working in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-comon-function-qjsou?file=/src/app/app.component.html)